# error C2955: use of class template requires template argument list

Tags: c++, class, templates

Not sure why I'm getting this error. All the functions in the class are defined. I tried putting a value inside T as well and nothing happened.  I keep receiving this error "error C2955: use of class template requires template argument list"

```
 template< class T >
    class Stack {
    public:
        Stack(int = 10);  // default constructor (stack size 10)
        // destructor
        ~Stack() {
            delete[] stackPtr;
        }
        bool push(const T&);
        bool pop(T&);
        // determine whether Stack is empty
        bool isEmpty() const {
            return top == -1;
        }
        // determine whether Stack is full
        bool isFull() const {
            return top == size - 1;
        }
    private:
        int size;     // # of elements in the stack
        int top;      // location of the top element
        T *stackPtr;  // pointer to the stack
    };
    // constructor
    template< class T >
    Stack< T >::Stack(int s) {
        size = s > 0 ? s : 10;
        top = -1;  // Stack initially empty
        stackPtr = new T[size]; // allocate memory for elements
    }
    template< class T >
    bool Stack< T >::push(const T &pushValue) {
        if (!isFull()) {
            stackPtr[++top] = pushValue;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    template< class T >
    bool Stack< T >::pop(T &popValue) {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            popValue = stackPtr[top--];  // remove item from Stack
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    int main() {

        Stack s();

    }
```

Comment: You want `s` to be a stack *of what*?

Comment: Actually no, you want `s` to *return* a stack of what?

Answer (score 4):

You need to decide what type of stack you are going to have here.

```
Stack<int> s;
```

This will make a stack where type T is int.  You can use other types here too.  Lets say you want a stack of floats.

```
Stack<float> s;
```

etc.

Comment: Jees cant beleive i missed that... thank you so much

Comment: Most vexing parse.  You've not declared a variable here but a function.

Comment: Use `Stack<float> s;` to create s using the default ctor